Adding '@vite-pwa/nuxt' to nuxt 3 project causes hydration errors
I want to make my nuxt 3 website PWA enabled. I am using '@vite-pwa/nuxt' for this.
When adding this package and enabling pwa in nuxt.config.ts it causes 2 issues:

Hydration errors start to occur when I refresh any page (class mismatch).
Whenever I refresh from any route it goes back to the homepage instead of staying on the same page.

I am attaching my nuxt.config,ts below :
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  css: ['bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css','~/assets/css/main.css',],
  devtools: { enabled: true },
  modules: [
    '@vite-pwa/nuxt',
      '@pinia/nuxt',
      'nuxt-swiper',
    '@vee-validate/nuxt',
    'nuxt-mdi',
  ],
  plugins:[
      "~/plugins/bootstrap.client.ts",
  ],
  app: {
    head: {
    }
  },
  pwa: {
    devOptions: {
      enabled: true,
      type: 'module'
    },
    manifest: {
      name: 'My Nuxt App',
      short_name: 'My Nuxt App',
      description: 'My incredible Nuxt app',
      theme_color: '#ffffff',
      lang: 'en'
    }
  }
})


Hydration error is occuring on this line of html code where the active class is added conditionally.
<li v-for="(navItem, index) in store.getNavItems" :key="index" class="nav-item me-4 me-xl-5 position-relative" :class="{ 'dropdown': !!navItem.links , 'active': $route.path.includes(navItem.route) }">

I get this error:
[Vue warn]: Hydration class mismatch on <li class=​"nav-item me-4 me-xl-5 position-relative dropdown" data-v-inspector=​"components/​common/​Navbar.vue:​76:​13">​…​</li>​ 

  - rendered on server: class="dropdown nav-item me-4 me-xl-5 position-relative"
  - expected on client: class="nav-item me-4 me-xl-5 position-relative dropdown active"
  Note: this mismatch is check-only. The DOM will not be rectified in production due to performance overhead.
  You should fix the source of the mismatch. 
  at <Navbar> 
  at <Default ref=Ref< undefined > > 
  at <LayoutLoader key="default" layoutProps= {ref: RefImpl} name="default" > 
  at <NuxtLayoutProvider layoutProps= {ref: RefImpl} key="default" name="default"  ... > 
  at <NuxtLayout> 
  at <App key=3 > 
  at <NuxtRoot>

I am not able to find a solution anywhere else. Please shed some light on what could I be  doing wrong.

I don't really see why this is a PWA issue. Do you have the same while using SSR/SSG and no PWA module? Could you also pin-point where exactly you have the class hydration mismatch? The error should be helpful to find where all of this happens.

@kissu I have edited the question with the error and where it occurs. Yes it only happens when I add the PWA module and when I refresh the page.

You have an extra active on your client-side inside of your Navbar.vue component. How do you fetch it there? WIth some localStorage or something alike? Here are some ways to fix it so that you have the same behavior on both server and client side.

Just read the other part of your edit, sorry. But $route.path.includes(navItem.route) is using Vue-router, thing that you do not have on the server side. Try to find another way of making such a conditional, by maybe using an API that is available on both environments?

@kissu The thing I don't understand is why does it happen only when I use the PWA module. The error does not occur when I remove PWA. Is it because the PWA caches the page in the browser.
Also why does the website go to "/" whenever I refresh the page when PWA module is on?

The hydration mismatch has nothing to do with the PWA module as told before, it might be a side-effect of your app but the error should happen without it too because it's a server issue. Otherwise, I am not sure about the default of the PWA module but maybe there is something like some cache set in place yes. "Also why does the website go to "/" whenever I refresh the page when PWA module is on?", I don't know because I never worked with that specific module. Maybe give a read to the GitHub issue for potential similar challenges raised by someone else.

Keep us updated regarding any solutions you'll find!

This issue only occurs when dev mode is on in pwa options. The best thing to do is disable pwa in development.
It works flawlessly in production. Here is the linked github issue if anyone wants to check on the issue on their github.
Github Issue
